# Java Unpredictible error with TransformerFactory.newTransformer

Tags: java, xslt

I'm facing a quite annoying problem making server Java processes to terminate, kicking out from this bit of code (condensed) :

```
_sesXslProc = new ArrayList<Transformer>();
TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
for( String it : lesFichiers )
{
    try
    {
        _sesXslProc.add( tFactory.newTransformer( new StreamSource( it ) ) ); // breaks there
    }
    catch( Exception ex )
    {
        ...
    }    
}
```

This code is ran on a server by a cron, many processes like this can be ran at the same time (5 maxi), and the ex.getMessage shows that :

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException: Chargement impossible de la classe translet 'cdt17totifv3'

EN : Unable to load Translet class 'cdt17totifv3'
```

Thus, I'm stuck with that and the manual launch of the processes is fine (generally, fails rarely).

Has anyone an idea of *what* can cause an XSL transform initialization to fail ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks to me like a problem with several different threads or processes trying to use the same resources at the same time and interfering with one another. Maybe they're generating a temporary file name based on the current clock time and thus sometimes more than one process picks the same name.

If you have several OS-level processes running at the same time, try giving each one a different value for its `java.io.tmpdir` system property, to cause them to use different temporary directories. If it's several threads in the same java process then I don't know whether there's much option other than to wrap the `newTransformer` call in a `synchronized` block.

Comment: Okay, I added a synchronized(tFactory) on the vicious line. I will post tomorrow the result of the night job.

Comment: Night job OK, waiting few more days to validate (or not) your solution.

Comment: Weekend passed, no more errors : I accept your answer since there is only that which changed in the code. Thanks Ian !